# Opening a file in VBA with a period in the filename

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
Dim WkOrigin As Workbook
Dim Dataname As String
Dataname = "09.22 Test"
Set WkOrigin = Workbooks.Open(Dataname)
```

I've tried removing the period from the name, and the code runs fine. Does anyone know how to get around issues with periods in workbook names?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to add the extension (.xls or .xlsx) on the end and it should be fine.

```
Dataname = "09.22 Test.xls"
```

You may be best fully qualifying it too:

```
Dataname = "C:\09.22 Test.xls"
```

Or if on a network use the UNC rather than the mapped drive, this way it will work on other's computers without the mapped drive or if it is mapped to a different letter (so long as they have access rights, obviously):

```
Dataname = "\\ServerName\SharedName\09.22 Test.xls"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This will be the first thing I try tomorrow morning, I'll let you now if it solves the issue.

Comment: +1. The `Workbook.Open` method requires a filename which (at least on a windows environment) includes the file extension.  Best to fully qualify it per your suggestion, without that I think it attempts to open from a relative path, which may yield unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding .xls did the trick, I have it defaulting to the same file as the current workbook.